# Import ember addon code directly from out of the box tests

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit, ember-cli-addons

I'm working on creating an ember addon, and I'm a bit stuck trying to write tests for it. This addon implements a command line option, rather than shipping components etc. As a result, none of the moduleFor type test helpers are relevant for me in the out of the box qunit tests. I'm not rendering any components, I just want a test runner to exersize the implementation behind my command line option.

To write my tests, I'll need to just require my various source files that are up in my addon. For example, files sitting in root/lib. I can't get a require/import that can find these files in a qunit integration test under root/tests/integration. Is this possible? I need a relative path like:

```
import foo from '../../../lib/foo'
```

But nothing up there seems to work. The folder structure created for an addon is like:

- root

  - app
  - lib (was planning on putting my addon impl here)
  - tests

    - dummy
    - helpers
    - integration
    - example-test.js (trying to reference code out of the lib folder from here)

It seems like my options in this case are just to fall back to some plain old JS unit testing (qunit, jasmine etc), based up in the root of the addon, not using any ember magic or the dummy app. I would like to stay on the 'out of the box' path provided by ember generate addon, but it seems like I need to go my own way here, so I can reference my source files.

Comment: `import foo from 'myAppName/lib/foo`;` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import foo from 'myApp/lib/foo'
```

Comment: Should have mentioned this in the question, this approach half works, but in tests for an addon, the root app is actually the dummy app in the tests folder. I don't know exactly what the ember resolver is doing, but its making the app root be the dummy app, not my addon app, the real root. And going relative from dummy ie 'dummy/../../lib' is not finding anything.